# How to combine free space with with root partition

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

I am having free space on my hard disk and I want to merge it with root partition

My structure is:

[image: structure]

So how can I merge both of them as shown in image

I am using **UBUNTU 20.04 LTS**

Comment: You can't directly merge those partitions. You have to move the intermediate partitions with a tool like gparted. Once the free space is adjacent to the root partition, you can merge them with a live Ubuntu USB. Always take a backup before performing such operations.

Comment: In order to give you a proper answer, I need to see a screenshot of `gparted`. Also, your arrow points to the extended partition, not the Ubuntu system partition. This re-partition will be a little tricky because of the extended partition, and the Windows partition. Do you have a Windows repair disc?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi There is no "root" partition... there is a Ubuntu partition, and it's not the one that the OP's arrow points to. The Windows partition will be the tricky one in this re-partition.

Comment: Forgot to ask... do you have good backups of your important files/data on BOTH Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: There's no obvious value in combining the two partitions. What is most important is managing the space in your system.  Create a Linux partition there and create a home directory for yourself or a project.  Alternatively, that  partition to mount your  /snap directory here.